# CSS Editors / GUIs / Apps with all kind of nice to have features

Tags: css, eclipse-plugin

I'm looking for a css editor which makes it possible to e.g.:

- change color with a color selector (something like [this](http://drpeterjones.com/colorcalc/) or [this](http://www.ficml.org/jemimap/style/color/wheel.html)
- support for css properties e.g. the typical CTRL+SPACE complete drop down intellij thing
- maybe possibility to say, group background colors from different styles together. So you change 1 value which gets reflected everywhere.
- maybe support changes on the fly in the webbrowser, firebug like, but better.
- more?

This can be an eclipse plugin or standalone app. It must be free.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try Sublime Text 2? I'm not sure if ti can do all those things but I've seen it doing the on the fly changes with Chrome (haven't tried it myself). It's not free but the version you download will just remind you to purchase it. It will still work fine anyway.

http://www.sublimetext.com/